# Does PostgreSQL provide Change Tracking feature similar to SQL Server change tracking?

Tags: sql, postgresql, change-data-capture

Does PostgreSQL provide change tracking feature like that on SQL Server.
this is what I basically want. I want to move my data after few minutes intervals to other database. for this I just want to fetch changed data only in PGSQL through change tracking like that of SQL Server change tracking. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so easy with PostgreSQL. You can use WAL’s aka Write Ahead Logs or triggers. May be the best approach will be using a external library like https://debezium.io

Comment: you don't need to read the WAL archives yourself. You can use [logical decoding](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logicaldecoding.html)

Comment: There are a few alternative open-source solutions for PostgreSQL data change tracking with Change Data Capture (CDC): [https://github.com/BemiHQ/bemi](https://github.com/BemiHQ/bemi) (written in TypeScript) and [https://github.com/replicase/pgcapture](https://github.com/replicase/pgcapture) (written in Go)

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to achieve the same goal. This is what I found surfing the Internet. There are few possible approaches:

- **Streaming replication** (ships a binary change log to a standby server)
- **Slony** (uses triggers to accumulate DML changes into tables that are periodically shipped to standby servers)
- **Logical changeset logging**
- **Audit trigger 91plus**

Comment: Hi, what you will suggest the best way among all these ways, I think stand by server data moving by using the Slony can be good one, as I can then use these trackings on the stand by db to move the changed data towards the sql server by using a running application i.e windows service